# How to change or set color of cell in MSProject programmatically in C# code?

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-project

I work on a VSTO Add-In for MS Project using C#. I try to set color of active cell using code like this:

```
foreach (JobDTO job in jobList)
{
    this.Application.SelectRow(this.Application.ActiveProject.Tasks[job.TaskName].ID, false); //this works.               
    this.Application.ActiveProject.Tasks[job.TaskName].Name = job.TaskName + "some text!"; //this works.
    this.Application.ActiveCell.CellColor = MSProject.PjColor.pjBlue;  // this doesn't work!              
}
```

I can not change color of active cells whatever I do. I tried to use `this.Application.ActiveCell.CellColorEx` property and set color using int numbers, but nothing helped me.

If anybody knows how to solve my problem, please help.

After all, I simply select needed MsProject.Tasks and add them some text using MsProject.Task.Notes property.  After this, tasks are staying selected and user can see them.

In code it looks like this:

```
              this.Application.SelectRow(this.Application.ActiveProject.Tasks[jobList.
                FirstOrDefault().Id].ID, false, 0, false, false);  // here I select first element in List , to avoid addin to selection some other rows,
                                                                         // that user selected before.
            foreach (JobDTO job in jobList)
            {
                this.Application.SelectRow(this.Application.ActiveProject.Tasks[job.Id].ID, false, 0, false, true); // add to selection rows I need.          
                this.Application.ActiveProject.Tasks[job.Id].Notes = "Some text"; // add some text to .Notes property.
            }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Did you try to run the code under the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

The [Cell.CellColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.cell.cellcolor) and [Cell.CellColorEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.cell.cellcolorex) properties can be used for setting the cell background color.

Comment: I run my code under debugger in visual studio. This code both throws no errors, and don't set the color to the cell.   But  when I do something like this after previous code:  MessageBox.Show(this.Application.ActiveCell.CellColor.ToString());  I see message with set color, inspite of the cells stay without any color.

Comment: "The Cell.CellColor and Cell.CellColorEx properties can be used for setting the cell background color." so I use this, but visible color of cells remains unchanged.

Comment: @MaximMalakhov  I found that the cell color is changed but not shown until the project is calculated (`Application.CalculateProject`). Seems like a bug, but a bug with a decent work-around.

Comment: Thank you Rachel Hettinger, but (Application.CalculateProject) has not helped me(.

Comment: After all I simply select needed MsProject.Tasks and add them some text using MsProject.Task.Notes property.  In code it looks like this:

Answer (score 0):

This approach worked for me:

```
Application.GanttBarFormat(MiddleColor: PjColor.pjPurple);
```